# How to find and replace hyphens with minus signs in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

When editing scientific texts, I often have to replace hyphens incorrectly used as minus signs with proper minus signs (i.e. U+2212). I'm working in Microsoft Word 2013 and trying to use a wildcard search.

So I type `(\-)([0-9])` in the find box, and `−\2` in the replace box.

However, upon finding `-1`, Word replaces the text with `1−`, i.e. it reverses the number and the minus sign.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with what you are doing, but on earlier versions of Word, the **Find and Replace** dialogue box has a **More** button: pressing it shows a **Special** button, which allows you to select Hyphen. This shows as **^~** in the **Find what** string, and you can simply enter **-** as the replacement string.

Comment: The minus/hyphen in your post looks different each time you use it

Comment: Your method works for me in Word 2007 and in Word 2013. I used the exact strings (with copy and pasre) in your description in “Find what” and “Replace what” boxes.

Comment: Thanks Jukka, I will check if I have some weird settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Word.  If you have turned on revision marking this happens every time.  Turn off revision marking and the proper behavior is restored.

Comment: Please be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state..